# MVC3 Model Data Separation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, razor

I've noticed in that a lot of the fields I'm putting into my views are control logic:

```
@if (Model.IsAdmin) {
  <p>You're an admin</p>
}
```

My understanding of how MVC should be working is that what goes into the model should act much more like a data, it's returned if it's a form, it's for the user to see/change, etc.

Is putting control logic in a view bad practice? What is the convention for passing control logic to a view in MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is putting control logic in a view bad practice?

No, you could perfectly fine have view logic inside your views to conditionally show or hide some sections. Your particular example is perfectly fine in a view.

Comment: +1 `logic inside your views to conditionally show or hide some sections` is the main point here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a lot of control logic in your views then my suggestion would be to deal with the control logic in the controller, and then have different views for different roles.

Controller Logic

```
if(IsAdmin)
    return View('AdminPage')
else 
    return View('UserPage')
```

The idea is to keep your views only focused on displaying the data given to them, and letting the logic be separated into the background (controller).

However, if you only have this happening in a couple places, then it probably is not that bad. Without seeing your full code, I cannot say for certain as nothing is perfectly separated in black and white.

Comment: even when the differences are small? it doesn't seem very DRY to dupe views all over the place to keep logic out of the views

Comment: That is exactly the point I am trying to make. If the differences are small, then this is not bad (as others have suggested). But, if half your view is changing due to control logic, then I would suggest creating another view. Also, if it is only content that is changing, then maybe you can create a model that is updated in the controller (as Stephen suggested). But, if it is just little items here and there, then you should leave it as is. This gets to my point that the answer is not necessarily black and white

Answer (score 1):

That particular example seems fine to me, you're presenting (the *view* domain) your data (the *model* domain), and what you get is based on the data you receive.

The typical rule of thumb is, if it's more complicated than a 1-2 condition `@if`, split it into different, better specialized views (or use specialized partial views), but really you'll never really see views with no flow control in an MVC project (not even just ASP.NET's implementation).

Comment: Very nice rule of thumb - I think I'll adopt that.

Answer (score 1):

You could add that to the controller if you want.

```
if(user.IsAdmin)
   ViewBag.WelcomeMessage = "You are an admin";
else
   ViewBag.WelcomeMessage = "You are a user";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using Roles for authorization rather than setting properties. like that.  Something like this:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
    <p>You're an Admin!</p>
}
```

If you like, you could encapsulate this into a [Razor helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) or create an Html helper to make this cleaner (if you use it in many places)